# I sent some USDT Tether to a Bitcoin Paper Wallet. Can I still claim it back?

Tags: paper-wallet, sweep, tether

I sent some USDT Tether to my bitcoin paper wallet. I have the private key, but how do I extract my USDT from this paper wallet? I also have some left over BTC too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can since USDT is built upon the Bitcoin Blockchain thru a protocol layer known as the Omnilayer. You will still be able to access the USDT within that wallet address so long you have the private key.

Comment: yes, but HOW do you do it?